# Change a attribute in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

How do I increment a attribute?
I created a type User

```
data user = User{
username :: String,
passwort :: String,
points :: Int
}

user = user {username ="Test",
             passwort="test123",
             points=100
             }
```

I want to increment the points by 10, I tryed to do something similar to this like in other programming lenguages `points += 10`

```
userplus10 = user{points = points +10}
```

(btw. this doesnt work)
creating a new user but with another value at points.

Comment: Yes, Haskell is a pure and functional language. You can only create a new user object with different values, you cannot mutate the existing value.

Comment: don't forget to vote!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does work, but you need to specify whose points you want to increment. `user`s, right?

```
userplus10 = user{points = points user + 10}
```

A better way of doing this kind of stuff are [lenses](http://lens.github.io/) though.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, Rank2Types #-}

import Control.Lens

data User = User
   { _username :: String,
   , _passwort :: String,
   , _points :: Int
   }
makeLenses ''User

user = user {username ="Test", passwort="test123", points=100}

userPlus10 = user & points +~ 10
```

Comment: Sorry i'm new at Haskell, do both things the same? and is one way better than other?

Comment: I'd argue that the lens version is indeed better, however it requires a heavyweight library and some pretty advanced polymorphism trickery (hence the `-XRank2Types` extension).

Comment: [This](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/05/program-imperatively-using-haskell.html) is a great article, suitable for those relatively new to Haskell, about how lenses enable you to write "OO-looking" code in Haskell. Also, while the whole of the Lens package is indeed a beast, there are various "simplified" Lens packages out there which give you all the most commonly-used features without needing tons of dependencies, eg. [this one](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-simple)